# Menu bar time stuck in UTC in 16.10

Tags: unity, time, 16.10, timezone, location

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 and ever since the time displayed in the top right corner of Unity has been stuck in UTC. This does not reflect the system time however as the date command outputs the proper local time and the correct timezone. In addition even my nightly cron jobs run at the right time. In the time and date settings in the system settings my location is unset and any attempts I make to try to set it seem to work until I leave the settings and come back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around I found out what the answer was. systemd-timedated failed to start because ProtectHome was enabled for the service and there is a bug where the daemon fails to start if either /home or /root is a symlink and ProtectHome is enabled. I simply disabled protect home and restarted the daemon with the following:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/^ProtectHome/#&/g' /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timedated.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start systemd-timedated.service
```

Now the time is correct and my location is retained in the system settings.